# HTML/PHP Contact Form PHP Error

Tags: php, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, contacts

The following error shows when trying to get my contact form to work. Previously worked on another host, wondering if it's the PHP version?

Error code:

```
".$_GET['s']."
"; elseif (isset($_GET['e'])) echo "
".$_GET['e']."
"; ?>
```

See here:
http://harrykirkby.com/other/malcolms/index2.html

Comment: That's not an error, that's just bad formatting making code appear on the website...

Comment: you can't run php code in an .html file extension.

Comment: If your file is fully HTML, so its extension is .html
If your file as even only one php code, it should be .php
You're using $_GET which is php. Use a php interpreter as easyphp or wamp if you're coding in php

Answer (score 2):

Rename file to index2.html to index2.php

and then write php code inside `<?php ?>`

ex

```
<?php

//code is here

?>
```

**Tips**: Improve your coding format

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse">Send</button>
```

change that to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-inverse" value="Send">
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your file extension should be `.php` and add `<?php ?>` tags.

Otherwise your server will treat it like html unless you rewrited your urls in apache. Change this:

```
 http://harrykirkby.com/other/malcolms/index2.html
```

to

```
http://harrykirkby.com/other/malcolms/index2.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Your new hosting does not treat html files for possibility of a PHP code which is normal. You can fix that problem by either renaming the file to .php

You can also modify your PHP.ini if your webhosting allows to allow translating html files as if they are PHP files.

You can also add an .htaccess file and add the following

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm 
AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

You don't need all of them, only one that suits your hosting

Comment: Thank you! Knew I wasn't going crazy! I'll update this now, thanks for your assistance!